# How to increase the load time of a Ionic4 project when initial render?

Tags: performance, ionic-framework, ionic4, pageload, load-time

For my project, I have used `Ionic` with `Angular`. When my ionic project **first** renders then the load time was too slow. This problem occurs because when the project `first` renders then it takes time to load all the `js` files. So how I can load the 'js' file faster which will increase the **load performance** of my ionic project. If anyone knows the better reason why the load time is that much slower then please tell me the reason and the solution.

Comment: Sometimes it takes time because of splash screen image size

Answer (score 7):

Because you are running in debug mode
in debug mode load time will be 7-8 secs
in prod mode it will be reduced to 4-5 secs
Also need to follow good practices while coding

Try to follow these links and tools in the link [Angular Performance Checklist](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist#network-performance)